# Why is it needed to invert model rotation to calculate modelview matrix?

Tags: matrix, opengl-es, 3d, dart, webgl

My code builds a model-view matrix by multiplying MV = V*T*R*S. See portion of code below (it uses WebGL in Dart language -- with some libraries). As far as I can tell, the code seems to work properly. However, in order to make the code function, I had to invert the model rotation matrix. Unfortunately I can't understand why the inversion of model rotation is required. Why wouldn't it work with the plain non-inverted model rotation matrix R' ?

Code:

```
// why is inversion of R' needed?
setRotationMatrix(_rotation, mf, mu, mr);         // _rotation = R'
_rotation.invertRotation();                       // _rotation = inverse_of(R') = R

camera.viewMatrix(MV);                            // MV = V (invert C into MV)
MV.translate(_center[0], _center[1], _center[2]); // MV = V*T
MV.multiply(_rotation);                           // MV = V*T*R
MV.scale(rescale, rescale, rescale);              // MV = V*T*R*S

gl.uniformMatrix4fv(u_MV, false, MV.storage); // send MV uniform to GPU
```

Legend:

```
[4x4 Matrices]
C:  Camera
V:  View (Inverse of Camera)
T:  Model Translation
R': Model Rotation
R:  Inverse of Model Rotation (why is this inversion needed?)
S:  Model Scaling

C = cf.x cf.y cf.z ct.x
    cu.x cu.y cu.z ct.y
    cr.x cr.y cr.z ct.z
    0    0    0    1

cf = camera front       vector
cu = camera up          vector
cr = camera right       vector
ct = camera translation vector

V = inverse_of(C)

R' = mf.x mf.y mf.z 0
     mu.x mu.y mu.z 0
     mr.x mr.y mr.z 0
     0    0    0    1

mf = model front vector
mu = model up    vector
mr = model right vector

R = inverse_of(R')
```

Comment: If you have the camera transformation and you want to compute the view matrix that will correctly transform vertices from world-space to view-space, you only need to take the inverse of the camera transform.

Comment: Actually camera.viewMatrix(MV) creates the view matrix into MV for me. I want to combine the model transformations into MV in order to get the full model-view transform (in MV). The code depicted above is achieving it already, but I can't make a sense of why the inversion of R' was needed.

Answer (score 1):

The R' matrix could be transposed which means that instead of the first 4 elements of the array representing the first column they represent the first row or vice versa.

With rotation matrices transposing is the same as inverting, so instead of inverting you could just do a transpose since that's much cheaper.

I don't see the implementation of the function that creates the R' matrix but the result of R' you pasted looks a bit odd to me: it corresponds (1,0,0) with the front vector not the right.
There's also the convention of multiplying the position vector from left or right in the shader which can also mean a change in transposing the matrices.
If you'd show an example url or more code this could be evaluated more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply two matrices.

```
M' = A * B;
```

Then it holds:

```
A = M' * B-1
```

MVP inverse matrix vector back again back to its original state.

```
V = PVM-1 * V'
```

It is important to understand the rule:

```
M * M-1 = 1 (Identity Matrix)
```